# How home prices behaves during and after great inflation 1970s in USA

Tags: inflation, historical-data, home, historical-analysis

Is there any chart/data or research on average home prices during 1970s in USA in big cities (NY, LA etc.).

I'm particularly interested in average price per square meter between 1970 to 1985.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good and detailed research paper from the Federal Reserve on housing prices.  It covers 1984 to 2004, and it might be a good start for your research.

https://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2006/200625/200625pap.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a "chart of home prices":

https://dqydj.com/historical-home-prices/

https://www.homelight.com/blog/house-price-history/

You can also quite easily google for the city you are interested in.

(Glancing at this, I see "no effect at all" in the period you mention, but, you have the data so conclude as you wish!)

> [image]